# What's the 0-percent-quantile?

Tags: probability, quantiles

Today I was asked what the 0% quantile is. I am aware that this has no practical relevance, but now I am still wondering. At first I would have said it was the minimum of a sample. R says for all types of the quantile function that this is indeed the case. But actually I think that it must be -Inf. After all, the value of the empirical distribution function of an arbitrarily small value would also be 0?

```
> x <- rnorm(10)
> summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-1.6150  0.2834  0.5663  0.4389  1.1797  1.4065 
> sapply(1:9, function(.x) quantile(x, probs = 0, type = .x))
     100%      100%      100%      100%      100%      100%      100%      100%      100% 
-1.406472 -1.406472 -1.406472 -1.406472 -1.406472 -1.406472 -1.406472 -1.406472 -1.406472
```

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical 0% quantile of the normal distribution is indeed -Inf. For the exponential distribution it would be 0.

Note that the 0% quantile is defined via the inverse of the distribution function, i.e. the quantile function as $F^{-1}(0).

For an empirical distribution, I don't know about any convention, since, as you noted, it is not needed in practice.
But if I would need to come up with a definition, I would not take the minimum, but the left limit of the minimum.

More explicitly, let $\hat{F}$ be your empirical distribution function and $m$ be the minimum of your sample. Then taking the 0% quantile as the minimum $m$ would lead to 
\begin{align*}
\hat{F}(m) = 1/N \neq 0
\end{align*}

and so the minimum would be the $1/N$ quantile, where $N$ is your sample size. 
But considering the left limit would lead to
\begin{align*}
\hat{F}(m-) = 0
\end{align*}

since all your observations are bigger than $m$, making it a valid definition in my opinion.

Comment: This answer seems to miss the point.  The problem at the heart of the question is that because $F$ for the exponential distribution is $F(x)=1-e^{-x}$ when $x\ge 0$ and $F(x)=0$ for $x\lt 0,$ $F^{-1}(0)$ is undefined and can be *any* value in the interval $(-\infty, 0].$ Either some additional criterion or a convention is required to specify what "$F^{-1}(0)$" might possibly mean in general.

Comment: If the minimum is the $1/N$ quantile, then the maximum should be the $N/N$ quantile and you're not treating the tails symmetrically. I don't have an answer to this approach beyond pointing out this inconsistency (which under a different heading leads to a small literature on _plotting positions_). To the question, a counter-question from me would be "why do you want to know?" and I might then be happy to say that with data in hand the 0 and 100% quantiles are just odd names for the empirical minimum and maximum.